# How can I create a Login with session in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, authentication, server

I've been looking for answers for a few days now and I can't seem to find something that could fit my needs. I want to create a login page with node.js and add a session to it so when the user close the tab and come back he has to log in again. Here is my server.js code for now :

```
    var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    server = require('http').Server(app),
    io = require('socket.io')(server),
    port = process.env.PORT || 1337,
    mysql = require('mysql'),
    pool = mysql.createPool({
        host: '127.0.0.1',
        port: '8889',
        user: 'root',
        password: 'root',
        database: 'admin'
    });

app.use(express.static('public'));
server.listen(port);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '../public/index.html');
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

    console.log('Un client est connecté !');

    socket.on('auth', function (data) {

        console.log(data);

        pool.getConnection(function (err, connection) {

            connection.query({
              sql: 'SELECT * FROM `users`',
              timeout: 40000 // 40s
            }, function (error, results, fields, rows) {

                for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                    if(data.username == results[i].name && data.password == results[i].pass) {
                            console.log('*------- USER IS AUTHED  -------*');
                    };
                };

            });

        });

    });
});
```

Basically, I have a form on my public/index.html that send data via js to the server (the socket.on('auth') get it on the server) and I compare the data to the database. If it matches I log *------- USER IS AUTHED  -------*. I now want to create a session to make it secured.

Sorry for my lame english I hope you guys understood what I mean.
Thanks in advances !

Comment: Sessions doesn't make it secure, but there is middleware available, like [express-session](https://github.com/expressjs/session)

Comment: Yes, i've seen these, but i can't seem to make it work with my code for some reason.. Could you help me please ?